# How to get to Resolute Bay from Toronto without going broke?

Tags: budget, canada, planning, toronto

It seems that this is going to cost a fortune. Are there really no cheap flights from Toronto to Resolute Bay?

Comment: What exactly is "cost a fortune"?

Comment: @Karlson it seems that it will cost at least $5000, you can fly a few times around the World for that price.

Comment: Given only 1 scheduled flight to Resolute from a "major" airport I can see this monopoly charging an arm and a leg.

Comment: All flights seem to go to Montreal, then to Iqaluit, then Resolute.  I assume the last section is the most expensive, but if you could bus to Montreal it might help a bit.

Comment: If there is no competition and not much demand then prices will be high.  Make your way to Ottawa and it seems you can fly for about $3700 on First Air, who are pretty much the only game in Resolute.

Comment: @MarkMayo Both the bit to Iqaluit and the bit to Resolute will be very, very expensive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there really are no cheap flights from Toronto to Resolute Bay.  This is a known problem, as small communities are hundreds of km from each other and thousands of km from any road.  Long distance flights in often hazardous conditions with small aeroplanes.  It means the local Inuit (unlike the extremely well-paid miners) are often unable to visit each other or to visit southern Canada, and inhabitants of southern Canada are unable to visit Nunavut.  Although the article mainly focusses on food prices, [this Huffington Post article from 2012](http://www.huffingtonpost.ca/2012/06/11/nunavut-food-prices-protest-inuit-poverty_n_1588144.html) also notes:

> Nunavut’s remote communities don’t have highway access, he says, and airline tickets don’t come cheap. A one-way to ticket between some Nunavut communities can cost up to $2,000, nevermind moving an entire family to a southern urban centre.

From Resolute Bay, you need at least two of such hops.  I am not at all surprised that you find tickets for $5,000.  I would not expect that you can get to Montréal for less than $3,000, one way.

For all practical purposes, visiting Nunavut as a budget traveller is impossible.  *Maybe* you can hitch a ride of a freight supply ship, but there are no official ways through which this is possible, and you'll be on your way for weeks, if not months.  If you try to get out by kayak, ski, or snowmobile, please make sure you are prepared for Arctic weather and Arctic wildlife.  Good luck.

Comment: Basically, inexpensive airline tickets come from economies of scale -- when you're able to fill up an all-Y B738 routinely the way Ryanair does, you can sell tickets much more cheaply than say, First Air, which is likely only selling a couple dozen tickets for any given flight, as well as having to give up main deck space for cargo in some cases due to the need to fly bulky cargo in and out.

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject Either that, or subsidies.

Comment: true, although another major cost factor is the need to maintain a much more specialized fleet of aircraft.  (In other words, you'd need a pretty extreme subsidy to take a bite out of the ticket prices...)

Comment: Well, that means that visiting the Arctic region in Canada is pretty much a no go.

Comment: @CountIblis Indeed.  The closest you can come on some sort of a budget would be Churchill, which is connected by train from Winnipeg, but there are still trees there.